# Does time-leaping move your mind or your body?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-girl-who-leapt-through-time

In The Girl Who Leapt Through Time, Chiaki comes from the future with a time-leap. Makoto eventually starts doing the same. However, Chiaki brought his body from the future, while Makoto just moves her mind to her past self. However, on her second jump (first jump on purpose), she actually moves her body too. The kids near the river claim her body vanished for a second.

So, are there multiple kinds of time-leaps, or did I miss something in the movie?